# ELK switch field to not_analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I generate the hash field in Logstash similar to this:

`{components: ["foo", "bar", "foo bar"]}`

I pass it to Elasticsearch and when I want to get the count of occurencies of each string I have only `foo` and `bar` in Kibana as they `foo bar` is splitted.

How to disable this split so I can get real values ? For now I'm using gsub to change all spaces to underscores but it's not the goal.

Comment: Logstash adds by default a `.raw` subfield to the index fields. And this `.raw` subfield is `not_analyzed`. In your case, you could search `components.raw`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I do not have any .raw fields, is it valid only for logstash-* indexes ? I use my own index like "statistics-*". I have Kibana 4.1.1, Logstash 1.5.4, Elasticsearch 1.5.2

Comment: Ok I found it in kopf, there is some default mapping to create raw field only if index is logstash-* :) Thanks